# SerializationException: The data contract type <TypeName> could not be deserialized because more than one data item <FieldName> was found in the input

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

Im getting an 'SerializationException' exception when deserializing data's from json file:

```
public static T Deserialize(string FilePath)
{
    using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(FS) ?? null;
    }
}
```

and this is how im trying to deserialize:

```
ServiceEntity resultEntity = JsonHelper<ServiceEntity>.Deserialize(DestinationFilePath);

while (resultEntity != null)
{
    ListViewItem listViewItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] { resultEntity.ServiceName, resultEntity.ServiceStatus.ToString(), resultEntity.DisplayName });

    lvServices.Items.Add(listViewItem);
}
```

T is this:

```
[DataContract]
sealed class ServiceEntity
{
    [DataMember]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ServiceControllerStatus ServiceStatus { get; set; }
}
```

JSON data is : https://pastebin.com/M18GD8yh

Comment: please provide your JSON

Comment: @letsdoit json is - https://pastebin.com/M18GD8yh

Comment: your JSON is invalid, please correct it

Comment: The error is complaining about duplicate items in the input. If the input isn’t defective, one of those data members might need to be a list or something.

Comment: @letsdoit i cant understand what is invalid, datas in json are seperated with , symbol and datas are inside { } blocks, can u please say what is problem exactly?

Comment: @padeso im dont using any list type on contract :(, im using 2 string and 1 enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is a single line of hundreds of JSON objects. The code reads the entire file and tries to deserialize it into a single C# object. You need to come up with a way to process each object separately. If you have control over the input file, it might be a good start to put the objects into an array, and deserialize that.

```
[{
    "DisplayName": "AarSvc_2dae3",
    "ServiceName": "AarSvc_2dae3",
    "ServiceStatus": 1
},{
    "DisplayName": "AMD External Events Utility",
    "ServiceName": "AMD External Events Utility",
    "ServiceStatus": 4
}, {
…
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

what you call a json, is not a valid json string, it is just a collection of json-like peaces in one string.  But you can easily fix it

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath;

json="["+json.Replace("}{","},{")+"]";
```

after this you can parse it as Json Array

```
JArray services = JArray.Parse(json);
```

or you can deserialize it in your c# class

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

List<ServiceEntity> services = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ServiceEntity>>(json);
```

or try your fancy serializer.

Output in a json format

```
[
  {
    "DisplayName": "AarSvc_2dae3",
    "ServiceName": "AarSvc_2dae3",
    "ServiceStatus": 1
  },
  {
    "DisplayName": "AMD External Events Utility",
    "ServiceName": "AMD External Events Utility",
    "ServiceStatus": 4
  },
  ....
]
```

UPDATE

If you have an acces to code to create a json from the c# object it is better to fix it there. IMHO you can use Newtonsonft.Json as a serializer . You can install it using a Nuget package. After this use this code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

 List<ServiceEntity> services = ... your code to create list of services;
     
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(services);
```

if you need to save this json in a file

```
File.WriteAllText(FilePath, json);
```

Comment: "what you call a json, is not a valid json string, it is just a collection of json-like peaces in one string" - thanks for info, this means "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer" is serializing not properly? im using built in json serializer which i said now, place of replacing text in file, how can we serialize data as json array with objects like this: [
    { "var1": "data1", "var2": "data2" },
    { "var1": "data1", "var2": "data2" }
]

Comment: @zeroG I don't understand what do you mean, but I updated my question. Do you still have any questions?

Comment: how u see here on post i used built in serializer "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer" and you saying: ""what you call a json, is not a valid json string" then this means "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer" is serializing not correctly?

Comment: and is there any way to serialize like array how u writed on final example part with help of  built in "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer" serializer ?